# How to add a new column, row and shape for a 3D array in numpy?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

The output of `a = np.zeros((2,2,2,3),int)` is

```
[[[[0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]]]

 [[[0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]]]]
```

I have a list Y = [a,b] and I want to add those like a new row, column and shape so that the new shape will be (2,3,3,4)

The output would be like this:

```
[[[[0 0 0 a]
   [0 0 0 a]
   [a a a a]]

  [[0 0 0 a]
   [0 0 0 a]
   [a a a a]]

  [[a a a a]
   [a a a a]
   [a a a a]]]


 [[[0 0 0 b]
   [0 0 0 b]
   [b b b b]

  [[0 0 0 b]
   [0 0 0 b]
   [b b b b]

  [[b b b b]
   [b b b b]
   [b b b b]]]
```

It is almost 2 days I have tried to solve it but I have not succeeded.

Comment: Usually we prefer seeing some of those tries, even if they produce errors or wrong results.  We need to know something about what you understand.  There are a number of ways of doing this.  `concatenating` arrays is one, filling in a "blank" array is another.  Have you tried something simpler, like adding a column to a 2d array?

Comment: I have tried to concatenate and I can add a new column or row but not the last one matrix which includes same element like a or b. 
I understood what you did and I haven’t thought that it would be so easy with a new matrix like you did with Y. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a starting array and target:

```
In [14]: a = np.ones((2,2,2,3),int)
In [15]: Y = np.zeros((2,3,3,4),int)
```

Filling the back grounds:

```
In [21]: Y[0,:,:,:]=2
In [22]: Y[1,:,:,:]=3
```

and then the `a`:

```
In [23]: Y[:,:2,:2,:3]=a
```

the result:

```
In [24]: Y
Out[24]: 
array([[[[1, 1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 1, 2],
         [2, 2, 2, 2]],

        [[1, 1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 1, 2],
         [2, 2, 2, 2]],

        [[2, 2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2, 2]]],


       [[[1, 1, 1, 3],
         [1, 1, 1, 3],
         [3, 3, 3, 3]],

        [[1, 1, 1, 3],
         [1, 1, 1, 3],
         [3, 3, 3, 3]],

        [[3, 3, 3, 3],
         [3, 3, 3, 3],
         [3, 3, 3, 3]]]])
```